# Throttling asynchronous requests with RxJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I need to send a large amount of data to a service. There is a limit of items  that I am allowed to send per minute and I need to send no more than 350 items per request, so I am splitting the data into pages and trying to use `Observable` to throttle the requests:

```
const maxItemsPerRequest = 350;
const interval = Math.round(60 /*seconds*/ / maxPerMinute * 1000);
const pages = Math.ceil(totalItems / maxItemsPerRequest);

let observable = Observable.interval(interval).take(pages);

observable.subscribe(async page => {
  const items = await getItems(page, maxItemsPerRequest);
  await this.sendData(items);
});
```

`getItems` and `sendData` may take a while to complete, therefore the requests limit might be exceeded in the second minute, for example (if the requests created in the first minute take more than 60 seconds to complete).

How can I make sure that a subscriber waits at least `interval` milliseconds after the previous request has completed before sending a new request?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you don't want to perform the action inside `subscribe` because there you have no control over when it has finished. Instead you want to make it part of the chain and the delay will start from the end of the previous call.

For example you could do it like this:

```
let observable = Observable.range(pages)
  .concatMap(page => getItems(page, maxItemsPerRequest)
    .concatMap(items => this.sendData(items))
    .delay(interval) // delay the emission from this Observable
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Pretty good. The only problem is you have whatever delay `sendData` gives ***plus*** the interval.

Comment: Yes, that's what OP wanted: *subscriber waits at least interval milliseconds **after the previous request has completed** before sending a new request?*

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that after I posted my answer. Still, what he wants and what he needs...

Comment: But also, 60 seconds wait is a long time - probably immaterial that the delays are additive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sequence that uses a Subject to signal when `sendData()` is complete and throttles the interval based on that signal.

The demo below has an interval of 500ms, but sendData is causing a delay of 1000ms. If you change sendData's inner delay to say 100, then the stream proceeds at 500ms intervals.

```js
console.clear()

const nextPage = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(true);

const interval = 500 
const pages = 8

const getItems = () => Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3])

const sendData = () => {
  return Rx.Observable.of('x')
    .delay(1000)
}

let observable = Rx.Observable.interval(interval)
  .throttle(i => nextPage)
  .take(pages)
  .concatMap(p => getItems())
  .concatMap(items => sendData(items))
  .do(x => nextPage.next())

const start = Date.now()
const show = (val) => console.log(val, Date.now() - start)
observable.subscribe(show);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.4/Rx.js"></script>
```

---

### My answer is totally (well, not totally) incorrect

It turns out that `concatMap()` is self-throttling, so the Subject is completely unnecessary.

From [learn rxjs - concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

> concatMap does not **subscribe** to the next observable until the previous completes

Here is the example code without the Subject.

```js
console.clear()

const interval = 500 
const pages = 8

const getItems = () => Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3])

const sendData = () => {
  return Rx.Observable.of('x')
    .delay(1000)
}

let observable = Rx.Observable.interval(interval)
  .take(pages)
  .concatMap(p => getItems())
  .concatMap(items => sendData(items))

const start = Date.now()
const show = (val) => console.log(val, Date.now() - start)
observable.subscribe(show);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.4/Rx.js"></script>
```